# Which control codes have be implemented in the control handler of a service

Tags: c, winapi

The [`SERVICE_STATUS` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996.aspx) says this structure has to filled out when calling the `SetServiceStatus()` function.

The third field is `dwControlsAccepted`.

Unfortunately I have not found any information about which control codes *MUST ALWAYS* be implemented/react to, at least.

The page says:

> By default, all services accept the SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE value.

But, is there a problem when the service control handler does not react to the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` control code?  Is there a problem when the service control handler does not at least call `SetServiceStatus()` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as `dwControlsAccepted` is concerned, there are no mandatory control codes.  You can set this value to zero if that meets your needs.  Apart from `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE` your code does not need to handle any control codes that you have not specified as acceptable.

For example, if you have not set `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` then Windows will never send you the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` control.  Any attempt to stop the service will result in error 1052, "The requested control is not valid for this service."

Note that unless you have a specific need to perform a clean shutdown (for example, because you have a database file that has to be properly closed) you do *not* need to accept shutdown controls either.  Such a service will continue to run until the computer is actually powered down.

If you always set `dwControlsAccepted` to zero, this is all you need for a control handler:

```
static DWORD WINAPI ServiceHandlerEx(DWORD control, DWORD eventtype, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext) 
{
    if (control == SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE)
    {
        return NO_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        return ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
    }
}
```